# How to get class indices from a quantized TFLite?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have been training a quantized Mobilenet V2 with TensorFlow, but I don't know how to get the class index from it.

I am using Tensorflow 1.12

Below are my input and output details.

```
Input details [{'name': 'normalized_input_image_tensor', 'index': 260, 'shape': array([  1, 300, 300,   3], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([  1, 300, 300,   3], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.uint8'>, 'quantization': (0.0078125, 128), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([0.0078125], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([128], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
Output details [{'name': 'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess', 'index': 252, 'shape': array([ 1, 10,  4], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([ 1, 10,  4], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}, {'name': 'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1', 'index': 253, 'shape': array([ 1, 10], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([ 1, 10], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}, {'name': 'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2', 'index': 254, 'shape': array([ 1, 10], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([ 1, 10], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}, {'name': 'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3', 'index': 255, 'shape': array([1], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([1], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```

I have been trying to get the class indices by doing the following:

```
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=PATH)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
interpreter.invoke()
classes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index'])[0]
```

However, the classes indices have been incorrect. When printed, `classes` looks like this: `[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]`. There are more than 1 classes in my dataset, so this doesn't make any sense.

What is the proper way to get the class indices?

Comment: Is your task classification or object detection?

Comment: Object detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of experimentation, it turns out it was not a quantization issue. We were using the wrong `graph_def` .pb file when creating our .tflite, so it was predicting classes that did not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
classes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
```

Comment: My issue is not with indexing the classes tensor, it's an issue with the values. `classes` looks like this: `[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]` when I print it.

Comment: Looks like model predict nothing. Can you use tf2? tf1 is not supported anymore.

Comment: We are using slim, which is not yet supported by tf2, as far as I am aware.